# Is there a pandas server?

Tags: pandas, server

Is there a way to 'serve' a large pandas dataframe in order to load it once, and then subsequently access it from another shell?

I am thinking of a uwsgi server or any other server. I have looked at django rest pandas, but I am not sure I understand whether it would do this.

Comment: Not the same thing, but [JupyterHub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub) does this on the notebook level.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [pyarrow.flight](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/python/examples/flight) with [pyarrow.Table](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html) `from_pandas()` and `to_pandas()`

```
# server
class FlightServer(pyarrow.flight.FlightServerBase):

# client
client = pyarrow.flight.FlightClient.connect()
```